# Pythonic way of returning from method using logic in overridden method

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, super

I have an inherited class that uses `super()` to call an overridden parent method. I would like to return from the child method based on logic in the parent method. Here is my implementation, but I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way of doing this?

```
class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter

    def method(self):
        if self.parameter:
            return True
        else:
            # Do more logic here
            pass

class ChildClass(ParentClass, object):
    def __init__(*args):
        ParentClass.__init__(*args)

    def method(self):
        return_from_method = super(ChildClass, self).method()
        if return_from_method:  # Is there a better way to do this?
            print('Returning from method')
            return
        else:
            print('Not returning from method')
            # Do more logic here

a = ChildClass(True)
a.method()
# > 'Returning from method'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to replace the parent `method()` and then call it via super, as opposed to creating a differently named child method and then calling `self.method()` ?

Comment: I guess I don't technically have to override it, but the child `method` really is an extension of the parent `method` so for readability and logical consistency I chose to do it like this.

Comment: As an aside, in python 2.7 you should always inherit from `object`. Better yet, *use Python 3*

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I use python 3 whenever possible, unfortunately it is unavoidable here for the short-term

Comment: *"more idiomatic way of doing this?"*: It's the way to do it, explain in more detail why do you think it's not ok.